# Delay in youtube pubsubhubbub notification

Tags: youtube-data-api, websub

I have subscribed my server to my Youtube channel using youtube pubsubhubbub. And I can see a delay of more than couple of hours between a video upload on the channel and the receipt of pubsub notification by my server. Can someone explain the reason behind this delay? Any help is appreciated!